# Drawing the slices of a 3D pie chart in the right order

Tags: graphics, geometry, graph

I'm trying to fix up an old application: I have a function that takes a pair of angles and draws a 3d slice of an exploded pie chart. I also have functions that take a collection of numbers, generate the angles and call the slice drawing function repeatedly until the entire pie is drawn.

Repeated calls to the slice drawing function draw over the top of existing slices and the order is never quite right. My question is how can I guarantee that the pieces nearest the viewer will be drawn last so the pieces overlap correctly?

```
function drawSlice(startAngle, endAngle)
  // draws a slice as shown in picture


function drawPie(list of angles to make up pie)
  for each angle in angles
    drawSlice(angle)

// example usage
drawPie([30,15,40,10,5])
```

A slice looks like:
[alt text http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/2627/slice.png](http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/2627/slice.png)

Comment: code? how can we know what doesnt work if we dont know how it is supposed to work

Comment: not able to post the actual code as not sure about legalities at work - will try and explain it better and put up equivalent pseudocode

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you'd have to divide drawing the slices into two equal stages. Both start at the angle farthest from the viewer and go in opposite ways.

After dividing the slices in two stages, you sort both whole slices and both parts of the one that was on the 50% boundary by their midpoint on the circumference, toward the viewer.

If there are e.g. two slices, first is 80% and starts at the angle farthest from the viewer, you'd divide it into two slices, 50% drawn in the first stage, then you'd draw the 20% slice that starts at at the top and goes in the other direction and only then you'd draw the remaining 30% of the first slice.

Sorry for the convoluted explanation, I hope you get the idea though. ;)

Edit:
To illustrate the case where a small slice is both overlapped and overlaps a bigger slice.
However note that this is not an exploded pie and this one is much easier to draw.

[image: Example chart for a Stack Overflow question]

Comment: Yes I kind of see - glad you understood my poor initial explanation at least! See my answer as I think you've given me the right idea to start with...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

mbeckish is right - this should fix it. Build up two lists with a 'cartoon-race method' - ie keep adding to a list until its total angle content exceeds the other list, then change lists and keep going. Once that's done, draw the 'smaller' one first. As this will contain at most 180 degrees it can never cross the danger point. If they're equal it doesn't matter. (It's not pretty)

```
define clockwiseAngles[], antiClockwiseAngles[]
define totalClockwiseAngles, totalAntiClockwiseAngles

for each angle in angles
  if totalClockwiseAngles > totalAntiClockwiseAngles
    totalAntiClockwiseAngles += angle
    AntiClockwiseAngles.push(angle)
  else
    totalClockwiseAngles += angle
    clockwiseAngles.push(angle)

if totalClockwiseAngles > totalAntiClockwiseAngles
  // draw all anticlockwise angles
  // draw all clockwise angles
else
  // draw all clockwise angles  
  // draw all anticlockwise angles
```

Comment: You need to make sure that the slice that crosses the 180 deg line (i.e. the slice that comes closest to the screen) is drawn last.
In your current pseudocode, it could be clockwise's turn, but the slice could be really big and wrap around to the anticlockwise side.  Then, when you draw the next anticlockwise piece, you will have problems.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the value of angle when pointing straight to us is 270, simply
calculate the distance of the slices' midpoint from this six o'clock line:

```
 Math.abs(270 - (startAngle + endAngle) / 2)
```

Then sort the slices based on this distance and draw in descending order.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is basically the right answer. It'll work in any half decent language, but in this specific application anything other than sort high -> low is not really feasible, and I will probably have to use my more long winded solution

Comment: See my edited answer for a case where the simple formula doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that whatever calls your function that draws the slice has its data in some kind of list, sort that list so that the closer items appear later and are drawn last.

Some code or other details would go a long way in helping give you a better answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just refactor to use whatever standard methods are out there to draw a cylinder from a given perspective, then color the surface of the cylinder to delineate the slices.